# "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I downloaded Android Studio and I am trying to create an android emulator for my app. The thing is that when I configure VSCode to use the android emulator this message pops up: `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK`.

I can open the emulator normally, but It doesn't connect with my application.

I've already tried reinstalling the Android Studio and also none of the youtube tutorials helped. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you able to open the emulator from Android Studio?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817988/i-try-to-make-android-studio-emulator-work-with-vs-code-but-have-an-error-avd

Comment: check installation path of android SDK and whether Android studio is pointing to this path