# Error problem in VS code for dart programming language

Tags: flutter

Every time I enter VS code and want an Android emulator Connect to dart language this error comes to me Please help me to resolve this error so that I can understand what you mean, thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAaJu.png)

Comment: What output are you getting from running `flutter doctor`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I try to make android studio (emulator) work with vs-code but have an error "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817988/i-try-to-make-android-studio-emulator-work-with-vs-code-but-have-an-error-avd)

Answer (score 1):

Run in your terminal `flutter config --android-sdk [yourAndroidSDKPath]`.

**If that doesn't work:**

Go to Android Studio > Settings > SDK Manager > SDK Tools.
Then select and download/update Android Emulator.

Now go back and open the AVD Manager and create a new Virtual Device.

The last thing you wanna do is check the Android SDK Flutter configuration directory.

Run in your terminal `flutter config --android-sdk [yourAndroidSDKPath]`.

Restart your VSCode.