# How do i solve "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK" error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

just installed flutter and im trying to create an android emulator but vscode keeps giving me this error:"avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I try to make android studio (emulator) work with vs-code but have an error "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63817988/i-try-to-make-android-studio-emulator-work-with-vs-code-but-have-an-error-avd)

Comment: First of all, I know that you need to create an emulator from within android studio but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after setting Java_home! you better look how to do that for your system. I am running on mac os and use zsh so edited /Users/[username]/.zshrc and added

export "JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"

in my case Java was already installed.. if not you need to install it.

Restart visual studio code as well